# Prove that fractional Brownian motion is not a semimartingale using the p-variation

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, martingales

> What follows, up to the horizontal line, is taken from [Rogers "Arbitrage with fractional Brownian motion"](http://www.long-memory.com/fractional-brownian-motion/Rogers1997.pdf).

Consider an interval $[0,T]$ on which is defined the fractional Brownian motion $B$, and consider its partitions $\pi_n = \{t^n_k = \frac{kT}{n} : 0\le k\le n\},\ n\in\mathbb N$.

Let $p\ge1$, the $p$-variation of $B$ is
$$
    V_p(B) = \lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} |B(t^n_{k+1})-B(t^n_k)|^p = 
    \begin{cases}
        \infty, & \text{if }\ pH < 1, \\
        0,       & \text{if }\ pH > 1.
    \end{cases}
$$
If $H>1/2$ we can choose $p\in(1,\frac1H)$ so that $pH<1$, then the $p$-variation is infinite, hence the quadratic variation of $B$ is infinite too.

If $H<1/2$ we can choose $p>2$ so that $pH<1$, then again we obtain that the $p$-variation and the quadratic variation of $B$ are infinite.

In both cases the quadratic variation of $B$ is not finite, hence the fBm is not a semimartingale for $H\ne1/2$.

---

Could somebody further explain the above reasoning? I don't fully get what has to be proved, is it related to the fact that a semimartingale has to have finite *variation*? But which *variation*: quadratic, p-variation or another one?

Moreover, I don't understand how to deduce what the quadratic variation is, given that we know the p-variation. Is it related to the fact that given $p_1<p_2$ then $V_{p_2}\le V_{p_1}$?

Fianlly, what about the case $H=1/2$, in which $B$ is the usual Brownian motion? If we take $p\in(1,2)$ then we are still in the case $pH<1$ and so the $p$-variation is infinite hence the quadratic variation of $B$ is infinite too, contradicting the fact that B is a martingale.

Comment: Why do you think that the quadratic variation of BM is infinite? For $H=1/2$ we have $V_p(B)=\infty$ for $p \in (1,2)$ but this does not imply $V_2(B)=\infty$ (i.e. non-finiteness of the quadratic variation). In fact, Brownian motion has finite quadratic variation.

Comment: @saz I was trying to apply (but without having understood) the reasoning of Rogers, who says that if p-variation is infinite (finite) then the quadratic variation is infinite (finite) too. But sincerely, I don't understand how to deduce what the quadratic variation is, given that we know the p-variation.

Comment: I'm reading that if $p_1 < p_2$ then $V_{p_2} \le V_{p_1}$, I think we have to use this fact

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $B$ is a semimartingale, then it has finite quadratic variation.

Recall that if $s < b$ then $V_b \le V_s$.

- If $H<1/2$ we can choose $p>2$ s.t. $pH<1 \implies V_p = \infty \implies \infty\le V_2 \implies V_2 = \infty$, i.e. the quadratic variation ($p=2$) is infinite too: contradiction.
- If $H>1/2$ we can choose $p\in(\frac1H,2)$ s.t. $pH>1 \implies V_p = 0 \implies V_2 \le 0 \implies V_2 = 0 \implies B$ must have finite variation. But on the other hand, for $p\in(1,\frac1H)$ we have $V_p = \infty$, hence $B$ cannot have finite variation: contradiction.

Either way, if $H\ne\frac12$, the fBm is not a semimartingale.